# Since event is deprecated for inline JavaScript function calls. What are the alternatives other that addEventListener?

Tags: javascript, events

I've already refactored all my code to remove as much as I can inline calls like onclick, onkeypress, etc.

That's fine and I really like the modern JS approach overall.

BUT, I'm struggling with tiny and very local function that would make sense to just call fast and dirty with `onclick="function(parameterA, event)"`. Here lays the problem: event is deprecated and is not recommended anymore.

Is there a solution other than using addEventListener to interact with the Event inside my inline called function?

Comment: You could just use delegated events for all you small events.  eg. https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate

Comment: Why you do not wish to use `addEventListener`?

Comment: Keith & Justinas:

I have a global initializer that defines all my event listeners. This initializer checks specific data- attributes when the page loads, or chunks of dom are added (via AJAX for example). That's fine and all. I like this approach.

The problem is that some functions don't need to be so dynamic, and I don't want to add them to my initializer. I just want to use inline onclick for simplicity.

Comment: Were have you heard that inline events are deprecated?  They may be discouraged, but if you believe they are the better option you should be fine using them.

Comment: @Keith Yeah, they are discouraged in the MDN docs – but in my IDE it's marked as deprecated. My concern of using it and in a couple of months it's support goes away from the major browsers.

If this object will be still supported in like 2+ years, I'm fine with that. I don't care so much about the recommendations – b/c it's a technically conscious decision.

Comment: Yes, you should be fine for many years to come.  Even this website is using them, the switch mobile link at the bottom for example.

Comment: @Keith Tnx for your help! I guess I'll document and implement it ;)